# Creating Word Docs w/ Excel VBA- Insert Images? Copy and Paste Text from 3rd Doc

Tags: excel, vba, image

I am trying to write some VBA code in excel to automate my task of building 100+ .pdf word documents, each following the set template. I originally copied a code from a youtube [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URF3ikW0Svc) showing how to build automated emails from a spreadsheet, and I felt my application was similar enough.

I can get the text replacements to occur as they should. My primary issue is getting images inserted where they need to be. I've attempted using a bookmark and replace code with no luck. I think my issue lies in my variables not having the correct value between the various subs, although that is only my uneducated best guess.

My next issue is creating a code to pull text from an existing document and paste into a new document. I'll be honest, I have been so stuck on the image issue that I haven't even looked into this yet.

I may be going about this task in an inefficient way, however, if someone may be able to spot the fault in my code, it would be greatly appreciated. I have pasted my existing code below. Hopefully it isn't too bad.

```
    Option Explicit

   Dim CustRow, CustCol, LastRow, TemplRow, j  As Long
   Dim DocLoc, TagName, TagValue, TemplName, FileName As String
   Dim CurDt, LastAppDt As Date
   Dim WordDoc, WordApp As Object
   Dim WordContent As Word.Range

Sub CreateWordDocuments()

With Sheet1

  If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please select a correct template from the drop down list"
    .Range("G3").Select
    Exit Sub
  End If
    TemplRow = .Range("B3").Value 'Set Template Row
    TemplName = .Range("G3").Value 'Set Template Name
    DocLoc = Sheet2.Range("F" & TemplRow).Value 'Word Document Filename

    'Open Word Template
    On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
    Set WordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        'Launch a new instance of Word
        Err.Clear
        'On Error GoTo Error_Handler
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
        End If


    LastRow = .Range("E9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Determine Last Row in Table
        For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
                                Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
                                For CustCol = 5 To 10 'Move Through 6 Columns
                                    TagName = .Cells(7, CustCol).Value 'Tag Name
                                    TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value
                                     With WordDoc.Content.Find
                                        .Text = TagName
                                        .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                                        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                                        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances
                                     End With
                                 Next CustCol

         Call InsertScreenshots

    If .Range("I3").Value = "PDF" Then
                                          FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("E" & CustRow).Value & "_" & .Range("G" & CustRow).Value & ".pdf" 'Create full filename & Path with current workbook location, Category_Model
                                          WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FileName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
                                          WordDoc.Close False
                                      Else: 'If Word
                                          FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("E" & CustRow).Value & "_" & .Range("G" & CustRow).Value & ".docx"
                                          WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
                                   End If
                                      .Range("O" & CustRow).Value = TemplName 'Template Name
                                      .Range("P" & CustRow).Value = Now
     Next CustRow


End With


End Sub


 Sub FillABookmark(bookmarkname As String, imagepath As String)

   Dim objWord As Object
    Dim objDoc As Object
    With Sheet1

    On Error Resume Next
    Set objWord = GetObject(, "Word.Application")
    If objWord Is Nothing Then
        Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        objWord.Visible = True
        objWord.Documents.Open "DocLoc"
    End If

    Set objDoc = objWord.ActiveDocument

    With objDoc
        .Bookmarks(bookmarkname).Select
        .Shapes.AddPicture FileName:=imagepath
    End With
End With
End Sub

Sub InsertScreenshots()
    With Sheet1
        For CustCol = 11 To 14 'Move Through 4 Columns
            TagName = .Cells(7, CustCol).Value 'Tag Name
            TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value
                    Call FillABookmark("TagName", "TagValue")
         Next CustCol
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot going on here and a lot of issues.

Key Points

1. Learn the value of proper indenting
2. `Dim` all variables, otherwise they will be `Variants`
3. Early Binding is easier to debug. Use explicit types rather than `Object`
4. Don't use Module scoped Variables unless you have a good reason
5. CodeNames can be useful, but give them meaningful names
6. Correct test for `Empty` is `IsEmpty`
7. `GetObject` ClassID is the *2nd* parameter.  I needed to use `Word.Application.16`, your installation may vary
8. Reset your error handling after using `On Error Resume Next` as soon as you can (this likely was hiding errors from you)
9. When using `EndUp` to find the last used row, search from the bottom of the sheet
10. Simplified the calling of your `InsertScreenshots` code
11. You already had a Word app and open doc, don't open it again
12. Simplified the Insert of image, avoid use of `Select`

Note: without a sample of your workbook and word doc I can't be sure there aren't other issues, *you will need to continue the debug*.

See inline comments on changes marked with ~~

Refactored code

```
Option Explicit

Sub CreateWordDocuments()
    '~~ Don't use module scoped variables
    '~~ declare all variable types, else they are Variants
    Dim CustRow As Long, CustCol As Long, LastRow As Long, TemplRow As Long, j As Long 
    Dim DocLoc As String, TagName As String, TagValue As String, TemplName As String, FileName As String
    Dim CurDt As Date, LastAppDt As Date
        '~~ to make debugging easier, use Early Binding (add reference to Microsoft Word), to get Intellisence help.  If you need late binding, change back later
    Dim WordDoc As Word.Document, WordApp As Word.Application    '  Object
    Dim WordContent As Word.Range '~~ this suggests you are already using Early Binding!

    With Sheet1 '~~ If you are going to use CodeNames, give the sheet a meaningful name (edit it in the Properties window)
        If IsEmpty(.Range("B3").Value) Then  '~~ correct test for Empty
            MsgBox "Please select a correct template from the drop down list"
            .Range("G3").Select '~~ will only work if Sheet1 is active
            Exit Sub
        End If
        TemplRow = .Range("B3").Value 'Set Template Row
        TemplName = .Range("G3").Value 'Set Template Name
        DocLoc = Sheet2.Range("F" & TemplRow).Value 'Word Document Filename

        'Open Word Template
        On Error Resume Next 'If Word is already running
        Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application.16") '~~ correct format for Office365 - YMMV
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0 '~~ reset error handling
            'Launch a new instance of Word
            Set WordApp = New Word.Application ' CreateObject("Word.Application")
            WordApp.Visible = True 'Make the application visible to the user
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0 '~~ reset error handling
        WordApp.Visible = True
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row '~~ use real last row  'Determine Last Row in Table
        For CustRow = 8 To LastRow
            Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(FileName:=DocLoc, ReadOnly:=False) 'Open Template
            For CustCol = 5 To 10 'Move Through 6 Columns
                TagName = .Cells(7, CustCol).Value 'Tag Name
                TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value 'Tag Value
                With WordDoc.Content.Find
                   .Text = TagName
                   .Replacement.Text = TagValue
                   .Wrap = wdFindContinue
                   .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll 'Find & Replace all instances
                End With
            Next CustCol
            For CustCol = 11 To 14 'Move Through 4 Columns  ~~ do it here, it's cleaner and easier to reference the Row
                TagName = .Cells(7, CustCol).Value '~~ Bookmark Name
                TagValue = .Cells(CustRow, CustCol).Value '~~ Image path and name
                FillABookmark TagName, TagValue, WordDoc '~~ call to insert each image
            Next

            If .Range("I3").Value = "PDF" Then
                FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("E" & CustRow).Value & "_" & .Range("G" & CustRow).Value & ".pdf" 'Create full filename & Path with current workbook location, Category_Model
                WordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=FileName, ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
                WordDoc.Close False
            Else '~~ don't need the : 
                FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & .Range("E" & CustRow).Value & "_" & .Range("G" & CustRow).Value & ".docx"
                WordDoc.SaveAs FileName
            End If
            .Range("O" & CustRow).Value = TemplName 'Template Name
            .Range("P" & CustRow).Value = Now
         Next CustRow
    End With
End Sub


Sub FillABookmark(bookmarkname As String, imagepath As String, objDoc As Word.Document)
    '~~ Use passed Parameter for Doc
    '~~ Don't need select
    objDoc.Bookmarks(bookmarkname).Range _
        .InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:=imagepath
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Things seem to be working correctly now. Is there a simple code I can add to resize the image? I can find things declaring the sizing but I don't know how to reference the image that was entered.